# MySQL find LIKE items in same column

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I have a MySQL database containing names and addresses, but there are some duplicate names with only partial addresses such as

```
Name  | Address 
========================
Smith | 10 Main St., Cincinnati, OH 45202
Smith | 10 Main St.
```

I need a SQL query to select all rows with a duplicate name and the shorter of the two LIKE addresses. I was able to use GROUP BY and COUNT() for exact duplicates, but I don't know of a way to apply that to substrings like the example above. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: do you always know the exact length of the shorter one? if so, you can use substr and cut all the values from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
select * from mytable as t1
 inner join mytable as t2
 on t1.Name = t2.Name
 and t1.Address like concat(t2.Address, '%')
 and t1.Address != t2.Address;
```

Comment: Possibly adjust the type of join, and add the count.  This example will only give the the alternates and will not include the base counts that you (presumably) have been able to get.

Comment: @JayDM: A left join would return the entire table. Counts were not asked for explicitly.

Comment: That was why I said 'possibly' :)

Comment: This is just what I needed to get working. Thanks for the help guys!